# is there a way to word wrap/pad one sentence to multiple sentences in go

Tags: go

write now i have a huge string which i get from 250-300 characters and i'm writing to file using

```
file, err := ioutil.TempFile("/Downloads", "*.txt")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
file.Write(mystring)
```

This writes everything in one line, but is there a way to pad the lines so that automatically after 76 char, we get onto new line.

found a solution which does exactly the above requirment.
made it a generic solution to split based on "n" length and whatever delimeter is required.

you can try it in the playground if you wish (https://play.golang.org/p/5ZHCC_Z5uqc)

```
func insertNth(s string, n int) string {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    var n_1 = n - 1
    var l_1 = len(s) - 1
    for i, rune := range s {
        buffer.WriteRune(rune)
        if i%n == n_1 && i != l_1 {
            buffer.WriteRune('\n')
        }
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a `\n` every 76 runes in `mystring`?

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes

Comment: i've actually added what i've tried, let me know what i should change :), will be more than happy to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/5ZHCC_Z5uqc

Did some digging in and actually found it not that difficult, posted my solution above.

Comment: Please post the code in the question body, not only as an external link.